# Adding Chosen to a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-chosen

I have been looking around and cannot find a good example of implementing Chosen, http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/, into a Rails app.  I am trying to convert my existing multi-select into a chosen styled multi-select box.

I tried inserting the files manually, copying chosen.jquery.js into my assets/javascripts folder along with adding chosen.css.  Also added //= require chosen-jquery to application.js along with the following code

```
jQuery(function($){
$('.chzn-select').chosen();
})
```

Also have  *= require chosen in application.css.scss

I added :class => "chzn-select" in a collection_select in a form_tag.

Also tried using the 'chosen-rails' gem (here is an example http://choppingbloc.tumblr.com/post/24894460392/multiple-select-boxes-with-chosen-jquery) but had no luck.

Anything I might be overlooking?  The collection_select is working, but it is not styled like Chosen.  I am a beginner so if there is anything obvious I may have overlooked, please tell - everything above is what I have done.

Comment: It can be helpful in diagnosing these issues to include any output that your browser Javascript console is giving you. Pop that open once the page loads and see if any Javascript errors present themselves.

Comment: Thanks - my console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: Prototype is not defined" and points me to application.js:4279 which contains `(AbstractChosen), n.Chosen = e, Prototype.Browser.IE && /MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent) && (Prototype.BrowserFeatures.Version = new Number(RegExp.$1)), t = function(e) {`

Comment: I followed advice of @Andreas Lyngstad and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it up like this

You have to include both the css file and the js file

in you application.css.scss, (because it is sass, do not use /* require)

```
@import "chosen";
```

in you application.js

```
//= require chosen.jquery
```

You should give your selects a different class or id than

```
$('.chzn-select').chosen();
```

because, it might make things messy when you debug the html. Chosen gives classes with this prefix like .chzn-done, .chzn-single, chzn-drop, chzn-search.

If you have a railscasts pro account.

look at this

[token-fields-revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised)

You should really drop the chosen plugin and go for the [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) plugin. It is based on the chosen plugin, but is way better.